# Hibernate : @JoinColumn behaviour in uni-directional and bi-directional mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am new to Hibernate and I am trying to learn mapping strategies. Now I am able to achieve uni-directional and bi-directional mappings.I found that `@JoinColumn` is strictly needed in case of `uni-directional` mapping,but not  in case `bi-directional` mapping.

**Why `@JoinColumn` or `@JoinTable` is required in case of`uni-directional` mapping,but optional in case of `bi-directional` mapping?**

Answer (score 0):

I would not say it is optional in case of bi-directional mapping.
It is just specified on the owning side and that means that specifying it on the owned side is optional and redundant. It is also not advisable as you would have to make changes in two classes when the join column names would change..

I did some tests and Hiberante would allow it.. but again why do it.

As the uni-directional mapping only has the owning side configured and you do not expect to be joining those entities from the other side of the relationship, then by implication:

`@JoinColumn` (appropriate for the uni-directional @ManyToOne)

or

`@JoinTable`(appropriate for the uni-directional @OneToMany)

has to be used.

Try to go through this article: [examples](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany)